# Select tag on form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a question in the select field of a form.
When I select option 1, the select field below would have to show some answers and the same thing for option 2.
I have a temporary solution, but only when I have only 2 options, I would like to know what to do and I would also like to know how I can pass the select text field to the class next to the change event. Sorry my bad English!

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="nome_completo" (change)="teste($event)">
      <option value="op1">Option1</option>
      <option value="op2">Option2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" *ngIf="gambi === 0; else op2">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="nome_usuario">
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ng-template #op2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="nome_usuario">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </ng-template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" formControlName="senha">
  </div>
```

TS CLASS:

```
public gambi: number = 0
public teste(event: Event): void{
if(this.gambi == 1){
  this.gambi = 0;
} else {
  this.gambi = 1;
}
```

}

Comment: You use ReactiveForms so you have access to the value using `myFormGroup.get('nome_completo').value` for example.

And if you have 3 options in first select use ngSwitch instead of ngIf.

Comment: but that way it would only change after submitting, correct?

Comment: No, your formGroup is directly changed without needed a submit

Comment: got it! Thanks man, I'll follow the tip!